# Access iPhone's built-in ringtones

Tags: ios, iphone, ringtone

I have a task to access the system ringtones in my iPhone application. I want to know if it is possible to access them? If not, please explain the reason.

Comment: Why did someone down vote this question? Perfectly legit.

Answer (score 2):

No it's not possible via the official SDK.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not Possible in `iPhone`, If you want to submit your app in `app store.`