# From my iOS app, How is it possible to set ringtone(default phone), alarm (default alarm), default notification, contact..?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, audio

My app contains sound/audio files.
**Are following is possible? if yes, how ?** please give some sample code.

(1) set ringtone(default phone) ?

(2) alarm (default alarm) ?

(3) default notification ?

(4) contact tone ?

**SET these things from my app (audio files in my project)**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access iPhone's built-in ringtones](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269982/access-iphones-built-in-ringtones)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Actually i have some song' ringtones in my application's project folder. i want to set the file as above four options. so Is it possible ? apple allow to do so ? if yes then how ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not possible to do any OS level settings changes from any private application. You can not change alert/ringtone/notification sound.

Due to security concern, apple doesn't allow this thing in Apple device, there may be several API or libraries which can be used in Jailbroken Device, but you can not post your app with these private api.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I think you are right. because I am not getting any reference or anything about my question..